# How to check the range of the user input?

Tags: javascript, html-table, conditional-statements, parseint

My goal is to prompt the user to input the number of rows and columns to generate a table using Javascript (refer to the code below). However, the range of the number of rows/columns should be from 1 to 10 (using **`parseInt()`** & **`isNaN`**). If the user inputs a number out of that range, there should be an alert saying "Row No. out of range - try again, page will be reloaded" and then "**`location.reload()`**" will be used. I've tried a number of times but failed. I'm a Javascript beginner, please help me out.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var rows;
    var cols;
    do
    {
    rows = prompt("How many rows? 1-10");
    }
    while (isNaN(rows));

    do
    {
    cols = prompt("How many columns? 1-10");
    }
    while (isNaN(cols));

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    table {
      border-spacing: 0px;
      width: 500px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: 20px auto;

    }
    td {
      border: solid 1px grey;      
    }
    -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>

    document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">');

    for(var i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
       document.write('<tr>');    
       for( var x = 1; x <= cols; x++ )
    {
       document.write("<td>"+ ( i * x ) + "</td>");
        }
       document.write('</tr>');
    }

    document.write('</table>');

    -->
        </script>
```

Comment: The best way to ask a JS question is to us http://jsfiddle.net/ . Upload your code on the site and put a link here, this way people can directly make a change to the code and quickly see the results of there action.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while (isNaN(rows));
```

with

```
while (isNaN(rows) || (parseInt(rows) < 1) || (parseInt(rows) > 10) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    do
    {
    rows = prompt("How many rows? 1-10");
    }
    while (isNaN(rows));

    do
    {
    cols = prompt("How many columns? 1-10");
    }
    while (isNaN(cols));
```

with

```
    do
    {
    rows = prompt("How many rows? 1-10");
    if(isNaN(rows))
         alert("Row No. Should be a number");
    if((parseInt(rows) < 1) || (parseInt(rows) > 10))
        alert("Row No. Out of Range - Try Again");
    }
    while (isNaN(rows) || (parseInt(rows) < 1) || (parseInt(rows) > 10) );

    do
    {
    cols = prompt("How many columns? 1-10");
    if(isNaN(cols))
         alert("Col No. Should be a number");
    if((parseInt(cols) < 1) || (parseInt(cols) > 10))
        alert("Col No. Out of Range - Try Again");
    }
    while (isNaN(cols) || (parseInt(cols) < 1) || (parseInt(cols) > 10) );
```

to get alert